# exact fetch returns more than request number of rows when trigger is executed SQL*PLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need to incorporate a Trigger into one of my scripts that uses Cursors. So i have one script with the cursor, and one that creates the trigger (called 'trigEmpRaise'). The trigger is created without errors, however when i run the script with the cursor (which ran fine before the trigger was created) i get these errors:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRIGEMPRAISE", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRIGEMPRAISE'
ORA-06512: at line 34
```

Here are the descriptions of the tables:

```
    SQL> describe empcopy
     Name                                      Null?    Type
     ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
     EMPNO                                              NUMBER(4)
     ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
     JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
     MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
     HIREDATE                                           DATE
     SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
     COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
     DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)

    SQL> describe emp_prob1;
     Name                                      Null?    Type
     ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
     EMPNO                                              NUMBER(4)
     ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
     DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)
     SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)

    SQL> describe empraises;
     Name                                      Null?    Type
     ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
     EMPNO                                              NUMBER(4)
     ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(15)
     SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
     DATEOF                                             DATE
```

And here are the scripts:
SCRIPT WITH CURSORS (WHICH TRIGGERS THE TRIGGER)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
vEMPNO          empcopy.empno%TYPE;
VENAME          empcopy.ename%TYPE;
vDEPTNO         empcopy.deptno%TYPE;
vSAL            empcopy.sal%TYPE;

CURSOR deptnoCUR IS
    SELECT empno, ename, deptno, sal
    FROM empcopy
    ORDER BY deptno;

FUNCTION calcSal
    (fDEPTNO    varchar2, fSAL  number)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
        fNewSal     empcopy.sal%TYPE;
    BEGIN
    IF fDEPTNO = 10 THEN
        fNewSal := fSAL + fSAL * .05;
    ELSE 
        IF fDEPTNO = 20 THEN
            fNewSal := fSAL + fSAL * .075;
        ELSE
            fNewSal := fSAL + fSAL * .10;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN fNewSal;
END calcSal;
BEGIN
OPEN deptnoCUR;
LOOP
    FETCH deptnoCUR INTO vEMPNO, vENAME, VDEPTNO, vSAL;
    EXIT WHEN deptnoCUR%NOTFOUND;
    vSAL := calcSal(vDEPTNO,vSAL);
INSERT INTO emp_prob1 
    VALUES(vEMPNO,vENAME,vDEPTNO,vSAL);
END LOOP;
CLOSE deptnoCUR;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SELECT * FROM emp_prob1;
```

AND THE TRIGGER SCRIPT:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigEmpRaise
AFTER INSERT ON emp_prob1

DECLARE
vEMPNO      empraises.empno%TYPE;
vENAME      empraises.ename%TYPE;
vSAL        empraises.sal%TYPE;
vDATE       empraises.dateof%TYPE := sysdate;

BEGIN
SELECT empno, ename, sal
INTO vEMPNO, vENAME, vSAL
FROM emp_prob1;
INSERT INTO empraises (empno,ename,sal,dateof)
    VALUES(vEMPNO,vENAME,vSAL,vDATE);
END;
/
```

The script with the cursor simply goes through each record in table EMPCOPY and gives them a raise depending on the DEPTNO they are in. It then inserts the new values into the table EMP_PROB1.

The trigger should occur after it inserts the values into EMP_PROB1, and place the new salaries and the system date the insert occured into table EMPRAISES.

However the error described above keeps occurring no matter what i do. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT empno, ename, sal
INTO vEMPNO, vENAME, vSAL
FROM emp_prob1;` must return exactly 1 row - no more, no less.

My assumuption is you like to do this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigEmpRaise
AFTER INSERT ON emp_prob1
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
INSERT INTO empraises (empno,ename,sal,dateof)
    VALUES(:new.empno,:new.ename,:new.sal,sysdate);
END;
/
```

Comment: Okay but im unsure as to why it is not returning only 1 row. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @DavidLacombe Everytime you execute your function you are inserting values into `emp_prob1` and your `SELECT`-statement inside your trigger is not constraint by any `WHERE`-conditions, so you are basically selecting all entries, which are more than one